# What kind of Database/Architecture should be used on server for large scale image recognition?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am currently trying to develop a mobile application for finding of similar images in large scale. I am using Microsoft SQL to store entries of each image and SQL store procedures to classify it,I am also using LSH for partitioning of data. But somehow I doubt that this is not the technology or way big companies are doing it. Can you suggest some effective combination which can be implemented on server side of my application to classify large scale database image.

Comment: Can you give a few more details? Are you shooting for a cloud deployment? AWS? Azure? Google? Host your own VM? Docker? My answer will be very different in each case...

Comment: I am definitely going for the cloud deployment. However I have not decided which one yet since its an early stage.I will preferably will go with Azure in future.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you're going to get a good answer here because the question is so wide open.

Without really deep details it's hard to say, but if I were going Azure I'd *try* to use Table Storage if I could.

Should be cheaper and faster than SQL, but only works for very narrow use cases. This *could* be one, but hard to say. No stored procs, but you could use Web Jobs to batch process.

One possible line up would be Mobile Services to process images coming in from mobile devices: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/, then Web Jobs for batch processing: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources/, and Table Storage for persistance: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/tables/.

Without much, much greater detail I'd be hard pressed to give you a better recommendation.